# PyAudio : What is the most efficient format and pack/unpack method to use in callback mode?

Tags: python, audio, portaudio, pyaudio

I am using pyaudio in callback mode with `paFloat32` format, 2 channels, 1024 frames per buffer, and I am interested in a more efficient input/output audio buffer data exchange.

To unpack an input audio buffer and get the list of float samples, I use:

```
fmt       = str( N_CHANNELS * BUFFER_SIZE ) + 'f'
in_floats = struct.unpack( fmt, in_data )
```

Using `struct.pack()` and `struct.unpack()` is quite inefficient and it takes significant CPU resources, almost the same as the audio signal processing itself. Since most sound cards are 16 bit, I also tried to use the `paInt16` format, but the results are almost identical.

What would be the most efficient format and pack/unpack method to use in callback mode (of course maintaining full resolution)?

Edit: PyAudio exchanges data using binary streams or buffers similar to the C data structures used with Portaudio. I need to unpack the `in_data` input buffer to get the float samples and analyze them. Everyting is OK, except the unpack is a bit slow.

Comment: `struct` is relatively fast. If you need something faster, you probably don't want to use python for the job. You can try to write the callback in C, or avoid unpacking altogether

Comment: You can also try `numpy`, but since you're dealing with relatively small buffers, the overhead may be big enough to negate the benefit

Comment: Why do you need to pack and unpack the data?  Anyway, numpy's `frombuffer` might be useful to you here.. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html#numpy.frombuffer   If you want to follow up, please post some minimal but functional code so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: The packing/unpacking processing is tolerable, I was just curious if something more efficient is available, as it takes significant time. I edited the question to be more clear. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) or the stdlib's [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module is going to be much faster, because most of the cost of `struct.unpack` isn't the unpacking, it's the boxing up of each float value in a Python `float` object.

For example:

```
In [1177]: f = [random.random() for _ in range(65536)]

In [1178]: b = struct.pack('65536f', *f)

In [1179]: %timeit struct.unpack('65536f', b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop

In [1180]: %timeit array.array('f', b)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 µs per loop
```

That's 100x as fast. And you've got an iterable of floats either way, it's just that it's an `array` instead of a `tuple`.

However, if you're planning to actually do any arithmetic on these values, you're still going to have to iterate those values—and `array` will have to unbox each of them as you do so, which is going to add back in a good chunk of the time you've saved.

That's where NumPy comes in; I doubt `np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.float32)` is going to be hugely faster than `array.array('f', b)` to create, but it will allow you to do vectorized arithmetic directly on the unboxed values. For example:

```
In [1186]: a1 = array.array('f', b)

In [1187]: a2 = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.float32)

In [1189]: %timeit sum(f)
1000 loops, best of 3: 586 µs per loop

In [1189]: %timeit sum(a1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 907 µs per loop

In [1190]: %timeit a2.sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.3 µs per loop
```

As you can see, using the `array.array` makes this twice as slow (I used `sum` because the actual iteration and arithmetic are done in C), but using `np.array` instead makes it 5x as fast.